# How to keep my wifi always turn on?

Tags: android, android-wifi

While disconnectiong to the selected wifi AP, my WiFi is turned off.I want to keep my WiFi always turn on while disconnecting to the the selected AccessPoint and in the meantime WiFi is n't trying to connect to other AP also.Iam using Android 1.5.Is there any solution for this?

Regards,
Rajendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mWifi = ((WifiManager)getSystemService( WIFI_SERVICE )).createWifiLock( WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL , "yourtag" );
mWifi.acquire();
// when done
mWifi.release();
```

Comment: Hi,

Iam using wifiManager.disconnect() for disconnecting the wifi.I think here iam wrong.how to disconnect specific AP?